# use php variable in name of mysql create table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys i want to use an php variable as a part of a name of a mysql table which i create with a query. I used two types of quotes like a example i saw on the internet. It should create an individual table name. `$cn` is not an array it is an single value. I have php error reporting enabled and it doesn't show any errors. Here is what i tried:

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE lm_Warenkorb_`".$cn."`
     (
     Index TEXT,
     )";
```

Why isn't this working? Is this possible or not? Hope it is clear what i want to do.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here... but does your database user have the `create` privilege?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE `lm_Warenkorb_".$cn."`
     (
     Index TEXT,
     )";
```

Comment: If `$cn` is from user input, you should also make sure that `$cn` doesn't contain any backtick or other illegal characters, otherwise a SQL injection attack may be possible.

Comment: doesn't work for me it runs through but no table is appearing

Comment: @SDC answer was given according to **Pgr456** code, assuming all check has already done

Comment: @Pgr456 did you select DB first?

Comment: triclosan can't you imagina what could be also wrong i selected database before

Comment: try to `echo $sql2;` after that try to run query in mysql-client.

Comment: I see extra `,` in your query

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to **wrap the entire table name in backticks**...

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE `lm_Warenkorb_{$cn}`
     (
     Index TEXT,
     )";
```

Also you can use curly brackets to insert variables into strings encapsulated with double quotes.

Comment: If `$cn` is from user input, you should also make sure that `$cn` doesn't contain any backtick or other illegal characters, otherwise a SQL injection attack may be possible.

Comment: @SDC - most certainly.  In any case, one should take care to sanitize **any** user submitted data that is destined to be saved/used at a later stage.

Comment: yep. I guess my point is that it needs to be sanitised differently from most other strings that are inserted into a SQL statement. The standard sanitation methods aren't useful when you have dynamic tablenames and fieldnames, but doing the sanitation is just as important.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will produce string:

```
CREATE TABLE lm_Warenkorb_`some_string`(Index TEXT,)
```

I think it must be 2 variants:

```
CREATE TABLE `lm_Warenkorb_`.`some_string`(Index TEXT,)
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE `lm_Warenkorb_some_string`(Index TEXT,)
```