# Using PHP variable as name of table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[use php variable in name of mysql create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624638/use-php-variable-in-name-of-mysql-create-table)

I want to use a PHP variable ( $userAltId ) as the name of the SQL table I am creating. However, despite looking at several examples, I have been unable to successfully create a table with this PHP variable. Using echo I have shown that the variable ( $userAltId ) does contain the predicted value, and if I plug in that value instead of the variable I can successfully create the table.

My latest attempt at the code is below, notice I use $useAltId three times, from creating, inserting, and selecting. Thanks for the help!

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'alexpnqo_johnny', '?KlI+TtfNEIO', 'alexpnqo_johnny');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();
$userAltId = $_SESSION['userAltId'];//I am passing $userAltId from another php file


// escape variables for security
$FBname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['FBname']);

echo $userAltId;//echos desired value

$sqlFriendList="INSERT INTO '$userAltId' (FacebookFriend)
VALUES ('$FBname')";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);";
}

echo "You have added ";
echo $FBname;
echo " to your friend's list!";
echo "<br>";
echo "Below is your friends list";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FacebookFriend FROM '$userAltId'");

echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
<th>Friends List</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FacebookFriend'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_error($con);";` extra quote `"` and `;` semicolon?

Comment: My bad, that was just a copy and paste error of mine when entering the code into this post

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks `$userAltId` to all your queries (table name) so that it'll read your variable even spaces.

```
$sqlFriendList="INSERT INTO `$userAltId` (FacebookFriend) VALUES ('$FBname')";
```

Comment: Hey John. I tried that, but unfortunately it did not work. Have any other ideas?